# select latest entry per day and corresponding data

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table in SQLite:

```
CREATE TABLE test_results(timestamp TEXT, npass INTEGER, nfails INTEGER)
```

I want to return the last pass/fail information for each day.  For example if the table contains...

```
2009-08-31 23:30:19|0|24
2009-08-31 23:37:18|0|24
2009-08-31 23:40:00|0|24
2009-09-01 19:02:13|0|2
2009-09-01 19:08:24|2|0
2009-09-01 19:20:29|2|0
```

I'd like a select statement to return...

```
2009-08-31 23:40:00|0|24
2009-09-01 19:20:29|2|0
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT t.timestamp,
       t.npass,
       t.nfails
  FROM TEST_RESULTS t
  JOIN (SELECT MAX(tt.timestamp) 'maxtimestamp'
         FROM TEST_RESULTS tt
     GROUP BY date(tt.timestamp)) m ON m.maxtimestamp = t.timestamp
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this query:

```
SELECT * FROM (select * from test_results ORDER BY timestamp)
GROUP BY date(timestamp)
```

If you also want to get the first fail for each day:

```
SELECT * FROM (select * from test_results ORDER BY timestamp DESC)
GROUP BY date(timestamp)
```

Comment: Neither will work because TEST_RESULTS has three columns, two of which aren't included in your GROUP BY.  I also don't see how SELECT * ORDER BY timestamp is going to retrieve the last entry per day.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solve this type of question:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM test_results t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN test_results t2
  ON (DATE(t1.timestamp) = DATE(t2.timestamp) AND t1.timestamp < t2.timestamp)
WHERE t2.timestamp IS NULL;
```

This assumes that the `timestamp` column has a unique or primary key constraint on it.  Otherwise there's a (small) chance you could get more than one row per day.